# Plotly : how to zoom only when intended

Tags: python, plotly

Using plotly I want to display charts of stocks and be able to zoom and hover in X and in Y direction.
I also want to display lines calculated by indicators en fill areas between those lines with a (partly transparent) color.
Candlesticks should be either red, green or blue depending on some criteria.

Allthough just learning and testing how things work I searched for how to do what I want and couldn't find some important things.

I managed to zoom in X and Y direction by setting yaxes(fixedrange=False) but with the result that whenever I click on the drawing and move my mouse the drawing will zoom to that area.
That's not what I want as in practice most of the time I might just want to move the drawing to make some space for new bars (is there an easy way to move the drawing to the left and up/down if needed automatically if a new bar is added?)

I would like to zoom after rightclicking or maybe doubleclicking first or holding the left-button pressed or ...
So I would like to know how I can avoid zooming when clicking on the drawing but still be able to zoom if I do 'something' while my mouse is inside the area.

I suppose others have experienced this as well and not everybody will like the defaault action and (hopefully) found a workable solution.

```
# fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=ha.date, open=ha.openHA, high=ha.highHA, low=ha.lowHA, close=ha.closeHA)] )

fig = px.line(ha, x=ha["date"], y=ha["alma"] )

fig.update_layout(title = "AEX HA Candles", xaxis_title = 'Date', yaxis_title = 'Price', yaxis_range = [700, 800])
fig.update_yaxes(fixedrange=False)
fig.show()
```